# Problem installing VLC

Tags: 13.04

I am new to ubuntu and using ubuntu 13.04! Its completely new and has no video player that plays avi, flv etc! I am using my phone to download so can someone help me please to download vlc for ubuntu 13.04 (site name).  I try vlc from a friend and it show something like vlc dependency not satisfiable! HELP please!

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install vlc` in terminal? Any Errors?

Answer (score 0):

you can install vlc-media player directly from Ubuntu Software center.

open your unity dash and type as `Software-center` then in the search box type as vlc and thats it you will get it listed and by clicking install you can install it fine with out any problems.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

open a terminal and type

`sudo apt-get install vlc`